# Map with Outliers in R

Tags: r

I have a map in R showing the level of Covid cases by municipality, but there are some outliers (e.g. in the example below the one above 14,000) which make the map look all white or very light red for almost all municipalities, except the outliers which look bright red. Is there any way to tell R to use a different colour for the outliers? I was thinking of maroon so that they still look like very dark red.

This is the code I am using:

```
ggplot(mydata) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=covid_cases))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(MUN = structure(c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), label = "MUN", format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    covid_cases = structure(c(0, 2257, 678, 1920, 5028, 3014, 
    14637, 221, 2059, 1352), label = "covid_cases", format.stata = "%10.0g"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You are missing some data with the `dput` output, as there is no geometry associated with your data above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do two geoms: one for the outliers, one for the rest:

```r
ggplot(mydata) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = covid_cases), data = ~ subset(., covid_cases < 10000)) +
  geom_sf(color = "maroon", data = ~ subset(., covid_cases >= 10000)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

The use of `10000` as a demarcation is purely speculative here and arbitrary. A more robust method would determine outliers via some normal method and store that as a property of each `MUN`, so that you could do (e.g.) `~ subset(., not_outlier)`.

BTW: while these geoms are unlikely to overlap, recall that *order matters*: in this case, the geoms with outliers will be layered above the others. I suggest you order them in the way that makes sense. (I bring this up because when using `geom_point` for instance, the outlier points can mask good points. Which is on top depends on what you want to highlight.

This works by limiting the data available for each geom. In `ggplot2`, the `data=` argument can be a `~`-like function, where the `.` is replaced by the original data passed to `ggplot2`. I find it better to use this method in lieu of hard-coding the real dataframe name so that when I adapt the code for other frames, I only have to change the original data name (`mydata`) in one place, not sporadically throughout the code. One could easily have done `data=subset(mydata, covid_cases < 10000)` without the `~`-function.

I'm using base R's `subset` here; if you're already using one of the other dialects (e.g., `dplyr`), you could use `dplyr::filter(., covid_cases < 10000)` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the issue :)